# Windows Forms Designer Changes My Code

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, desktop-application

Im trying to create desktop application in VB Express 2013. User should be able to change main form size with mouse. But I want to keep some controls in the middle without changing size.

So when I have Panel called Panel1 its set like this:

```
Me.Panel1.location= New System.Drawing.Point((Me.Width/2)-(Me.Panel1.Width/2),0)
```

This will keep panel in the middle but when I add some other control (let´s say menu strip), the designer page rewrite itself and my settings is gone.

So my question is this:
When (or where) is the best time and way to set these settings. Should I do this in like Form_Load event or something?

Is there a way to stop VB Express from overwriting my code?

Comment: Where did you change the `Location`? In the designer-generated code? Don't _do_ that. That code belongs to the designer, not to you. The designer will overwrite that code whenever it wants to!

Comment: @JohnSaunders but where should I set accurate position of control element? There isn´t anything like POSITION:CENTER

Comment: That's the kind of thing to put into the `Load` event. Definitely don't do it in the `InitializeComponent` code which is generated by the designer.

Comment: Ok I will try it but should I be able to edit everything in designer? What is the point of designer then

Comment: "Required method for Designer support - do not modify the contents of this method with the code editor." That's what it says in the Windows Forms program I just created. The purpose of the designer is to do the creation and property setting for you. But then the designer owns the .Designer.vb file. You do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .Designer.vb file (or .designer.cs in C#) belongs to the Windows Forms Designer. It is *not your code*. It is generated by a tool. In most situations where code is generated by a tool, you must *not* touch the generated code. Instead, you must either "touch" whatever causes the tool to generate the code (in this case, the designer surface in Visual Studio) or else make code changes elsewhere - somewhere the tool won't touch.

For instance, double-click the form in the designer, and it will create a `Load` event for you. Add the code to change the `Location` to that event:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Panel1.Location = _
            New System.Drawing.Point(CInt((Me.Width / 2) - (Me.Panel1.Width / 2)), 0)
    End Sub
End Class
```

For anyone who looks inside the designer code, they left the following warning:

```
'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
```

(in C#, it says "Required method for Designer support - do not modify the contents of this method with the code editor." )

Answer (score 1):

Any code which resizes or affects the position of controls in a form should be placed in the

> Form_Resize Event

By placing the code in there, it will be executed every time the form is resized. Which is what you want really.

If you place any resizing code in your Form_Load event it will ONLY be executed when the form is loaded!

Comment: it will be executed every time the form is resized @ Runtime not design time

Comment: Since Im new at this, it´s good to know there exists **Form_Resize** event. I will need that too. Thanks

Comment: As your question originally stated....'User should be able to change main form size with mouse' I assumed you would resize the form, maybe I misunderstood that you were referring to design time issues? Still though, run your app and resize your window, I would expect nothing is resized inside your window then?

Comment: So far is my Panel1 element staying in the middle without changing its own size.

Comment: Yes that behaviour is expected when you use the Form_Load event to initially size and locate the panel. When you resize your window it (the panel) will remain the same.

Comment: Is Form_Load called with resizing the window? Let´s say that I have window and Its width is 10. Inside Form_Load is calculation for center position, in this case 5. When I resize the window to twice of its own size element is correctly positioned in the middle (10). So the Form_Load must be called with Form_Resize, right?

Comment: No Form_LOAD is only called when LOADing the form!
Form load event - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
Form resize event - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resize(v=vs.110).aspx